# Can't play mp3 file in an infinite loop

Tags: cocoa

I am trying to play a music file with eternal loop.
My code is:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"theme" ofType:@"mp3" inDirectory:@"assets/audios" ];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

NSError *error;
AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;
audioPlayer.volume = 1.0;
if (audioPlayer == nil){
    NSLog(@"Error creating player: %@", error);
}
[audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
[audioPlayer play];
```

But it does nothing. Nothing is played and any message log is printed.

The code below works great:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"theme" ofType:@"mp3" inDirectory:@"assets/audios" ];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
SystemSoundID soundID;
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef)CFBridgingRetain(url), &soundID);
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (soundID);
```

But I need to control the volume and the loop.

I dont know what Im doing wrong.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: I suspect that the `AVAudioPlayer` instance is getting deallocated. What happens when you keep a strong reference to it after creation?

Comment: @property (strong, nonatomic) AVAudioPlayer *player; ? No effect